# jqGrid TreeGrid is not working in adjacency mode in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, jqgrid, internet-explorer-9, backwards-compatibility, treegrid

I cannot for the life of me figure this out. jqGrid works in nested mode as well as regular mode, but even this jqGrid demo's adjacency mode doesn't work in IE 9 or 8: 
http://www.guriddo.net/demo/treegridjs/

It just loads forever when I use anything below IE 10.

The moment I remove "treegrid=true," from my code or the guriddo adjacency code, it works, it just does not have the proper tree structure.

This is what the code looks like:

```
        $(".tableHolder").prepend("<table id='"+tableid+"' style='overflow:auto;'></table>");
        //Creates the jqgrid table that the user will use
        jQuery('#'+tableid).jqGrid({
            "datastr": JSONdata,
            "datatype": 'jsonstring',
            "colModel":[
                {
                    "name":"emp_id",
                    "index":"emp_id",
                    "sorttype":"int",
                    "key":true,
                    "hidden":true
                },{
                    "name":"name",
                    "index":"name",
                    "sorttype":"string",
                    "label":"Name",
                    "width":175
                }]
                .concat(subcolumns)
                .concat([
                {
                    "name":"boss_id",
                    "hidden":true
                }
            ]),
            cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
            "hoverrows":false,
            "viewrecords":false,
            //"gridview":true,
            "height":"auto",
            "sortname":"emp_id",
            "scrollrows":true,

            "treeGrid":true,
            "ExpandColumn":"name",
            "ExpandColClick" : true,
            "treedatatype":"json",
            "treeGridModel":"adjacency",
            "loadonce":true,
            "rowNum":100,
            "treeReader":{
                "parent_id_field":"boss_id",
                "level_field":"level",
                "leaf_field":"isLeaf",
                "expanded_field":"expanded",
                "loaded":"loaded",
                "icon_field":"icon"
            },
            "pager":"#pager",
            caption: name,

            onCellSelect: function(id,cellidx,cellvalue) { 
                //Irrelevant cell select code
            },          
            loadComplete: function(data){
                //Irrelevant load complete code
            }
        }); 


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't included the test data. So the format of `datatype` is unclear. I suppose that your problem exist because of the bug in jqGrid 4.7.x version. It works incorrectly if you use input data in `repeatitems: true` format (inems inside of array instead of usage named properties) and `key:true`.

As a workaround I can suggest you to remove `key:true` from `emp_id` column and add `localReader: { id: 0 }` (the 0 is the index of id column in array of items of input data). I hope it will fix your problem.

Alternatively you can try new free version of jqGrid which I develop currently and publish of GitHub [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid). It's a fork of the latest free version of jqGrid (4.7.0), where I'v fixed a lot of small bugs and have implemented some new features. You should take in consideration that the version is still in beta phase.